# Compare the selected dates of two aspxCalenders

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I have two calenders, a StartDate Calender and an EndDate Calender, the basic rules for this are normal, the EndDate cant be before the start date, and the StartDate and EndDate cant be before today's date.

I tried this, and it didn't work.

```
if (EndDateCalender.SelectedDate < StartDateCalender.SelectedDate)
{
ErrorLabel.Text = "The End Date Cant Be Before the Start Date";
}

if (StartDateCalender.SelectedDate < DateTime.Now)
{
ErrorLabel.Text = "The StartDate Cant be before this day...";
}

if (EndDateCalender.SelectedDate < DateTime.Now)
{
ErrorLabel.Text = "The EndDate Cant be before this day...";
}
```

Comment: What is your error code? Which lines gives you an error?

Comment: it doesn't give an error, it just runs normally and ignores my code.

Comment: Which lines of code have ignored?

Comment: Does it runs these lines? Have you tried set breakpoint on one of those ifs and debug? And in what function are those lines of code?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i did this and it finally worked, I think the lack of an else statement for each one was the problem... Thanks for your time guys :)

```
    if (EndDateCalender.SelectedDate >= StartDateCalender.SelectedDate 
&& StartDateCalender.SelectedDate >= DateTime.Now 
&& EndDateCalender.SelectedDate > DateTime.Now)
{
//My Code
}
Else
{
ErrorLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("Red");
ErrorLabel.Text = " Invalid Date...";
}
```